# AutoCompleteTextView set OnClickListener on Keyboard-SearchButton

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview, clicklistener

how can I set an OnClickListener on the keyboard search button?

I added to my ACTV the imeOptions attribute. So i have a searchbutton instead of a enter button.

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```

I already have a solution, but this only works with an editText.

```
actv.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                performSearch();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

How can I make this work on an AutoCompleteTextView or is there any code which works better? if i use this code, eclipse says that the listener isn't available for the actv.

Thanks